# Entity Framework error: A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column.Column: 'Id'

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Let's say that I have three tables with primary keys as "Stored Generated Pattern".

`Table1` and `Table2` are associated with `Table3` in one-to-one relationship. This means: `Table3` can only have one instance of `table1`

```
public partial class table1
{      
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public virtual Table3 Table3 { get; set; }
}

public partial class table2
{      
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public virtual Table3 Table3 { get; set; }
}

public partial class Table3
{
    public Table3() { }
    public Table3(table1 s) { this.table1 = s; this.table2 = null; }
    public Table3(table2 t) { this.table2 = t; this.table1 = null; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public virtual table1 table1 { get; set; }
    public virtual table2 table2 { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
Table1 T1 = new Table1()
            {
                name = obj.table1.name,
            };

db.Students.Add(T1);
db.SaveChanges();   // works sucessfully 
                                // Data in inserted
Table3 t3 = new Table3()
            {
                name = obj.name,
                table1 = T1,
                table2 = null
            };

db.Users.Add(u);  // here error occurs 
db.SaveChanges(); //InvalidOperationException:
```

**Problem :**

In controller, when I try to insert into database, `Table1` is inserted and `Table2`  throws an error:

> A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column.Column: 'Id'.

Why does it cause this error?

Normally in database, you insert Id of the foreign key. However, in Entity Framework, you have the object of entire table `table3.table1.name`. Any explanation to remove this error?

Comment: You've defined two one to one relationships.  A one to one relationship means that for every table 3, you will have both a table 1 and a table 2, so your statement "Table1 and Table2 are associated with Table3 in one-to-one relationship. This means: Table3 can only have one instance of table1" is incorrect.  More like Table1 and Table2 are associated with Table3 in one-to-one relationship. This means: Table3 must have have one instance of table1 and one instance of table2. Looking at your code it appears you actually might want two 1 to 0..1 relationships however.

Comment: I have done that as well. After creating a new project. 
0..1 Table3  -----------  1 Table1
0..1 Table3  -----------  1 Table2

Answer (score 1):

The default convention for integer keys in EF is to generate them at the database, but where you have 1-1 relationships only the principal table can have a database-generated key.  That key is then re-used as the key of the dependent entity.

eg

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp8
{

    public partial class Table1
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual Table3 Table3 { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Table2
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual Table3 Table3 { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Table3
    {
        public Table3() { }
        public Table3(Table1 s) { this.Table1 = s; this.Table2 = null; }
        public Table3(Table2 t) { this.Table2 = t; this.Table1 = null; }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual Table1 Table1 { get; set; }
        public virtual Table2 Table2 { get; set; }
    }

    class Db : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Table1> Table1 { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Table2> Table2 { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Table3> Table3 { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Table1>()
                        .HasOptional(t => t.Table3)
                        .WithOptionalPrincipal(t1 => t1.Table1);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Table2>()
                        .HasOptional(t => t.Table3)
                        .WithOptionalDependent(t => t.Table2);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Table1>()
                        .Property(t => t.Id)
                        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Table2>()
            .Property(t => t.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Table3>()
            .Property(t => t.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);


        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new Db())
            {


                Table1 T1 = new Table1()
                {
                    Name = "Foo"
                };

                db.Table1.Add(T1);
                db.SaveChanges();   // works sucessfully 
                                    // Data in inserted
                Table3 t3 = new Table3()
                {
                    Name = "Bar",
                    Table1 = T1,
                    Table2 = null
                };

                db.Table3.Add(t3);
                db.SaveChanges(); 

                var t2 = new Table2()
                {
                    Name = "Baz",
                    Table3 = t3
                };
                db.Table2.Add(t2);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```